# How do I redirect a link to a JPG image on my IIS 7.5 server to a different drive?

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, redirect, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

Ok I am running Win 2008 Server R2 with IIS 7.5. My current directory structure is something like this:

```
C:\websites\index.php
C:\websites\images\image1.jpg
```

For example purposes, the URL to these files would be http://www.mysite.com/ and http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg

I want to move the location of my images folder to D:, so it would look something like this:

```
D:\websites\images\image1.jpg
```

but have it so the URL stays the same at http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg. Basically I want every link that goes to http://www.mysite.com/images/ to get it from D: instead of C: now.

How do I do this? Do I need a rewrite rule? How do I have a website (in this case mysite.com) in IIS point to two different directories, one in C:\websites\ and the other in D:\websites\ at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the IIS Manager graphical user interface, you have to create a virtual directory called `images` in the root of your website and let it point to the images folder on the D: drive.